# Combine Meshes with AutoSmooth data

Tags: modeling

I have a large and very complicated mesh, currently broken into a few separate parts. It is a game asset.
Part of it is a main Body, it is a hard body mesh, so I use AutoSmooth set to 30d to add the correct smoothing group detail all over the body.
The pipes, however, are set to 60d. When combining the two, one will mess up and inherent the Auto-Smooth data from the other.
Is there a way to combine the two whilst still retaining the AutoSmooth data without individually marking Sharps ALL over the massive mesh.
Thanks!

PS. I can't use Edge split for obvious reason :S

Comment: What are the obvious reasons for not using (and applying) the edge split modifier?

Comment: Because it's a Game asset, and I can't obliterate the Mesh islands. haha.